# Trigger a changed value from jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML input field that is hidden.

```
<input type=hidden id=menutext>
```

this HTML field is triggered from an jQuery function with its value

```
$('#menutext').val(something);
```

How can I trigger a function when my hidden field gets changed using jQuery. As `.change` works if I loose focus on a input.

Comment: `$('#menutext').val(something).change();`

Comment: You can also execute almost any other event using `.trigger('eventName')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val() does not trigger any event you have to trigger them manually after assigning the value to your input.

Comment: How can I do that beside interact myself?

Comment: have got it working now, @sergioadh you gave me an idee, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `val()` function and make it trigger `change()`:

```
(function ($) {
  var originalVal = $.fn.val;
  $.fn.val = function(value) {
    var original = originalVal.call(this, value);
    this.change();
    return original;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ApZax/

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to override functions like that; dangerous stuff!

Comment: @frenchie Sure thing, I agree. Although this is a small change, overriding like this demands care. It is an alternative to manual triggering, anyway.